# How do I create a panel of timers that start at different times

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a panel of timers, when the page loads each timer could have a different amount of time remaining. I have the following directive, which doesn't quite. The attribute "counter" doesn't allow the timers to maintain scope, i.e. they both are starting at the same time remaining when they tick down. How do I edit the following code to allow for this?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('TimerController', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.timers = function() {
            $http.get('/timers').
            then(function(response) {
                $scope.timers = response.data.results
            }, function(response) {});
        }

        $scope.Math = window.Math;

    }).directive('timer', function() {

        template_string = '<h5>{{Math.floor(counter/60)}} minutes {{counter-Math.floor(counter/60)*60}} seconds</h5>'

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: template_string,
            controller: function($scope, $timeout, $attrs) {
                $scope.counter = parseInt($attrs.counter, 10) || 3600
                var callback = function() {
                    $scope.done = ($scope.counter <= 0) ? true : false;
                    ($scope.done) ? $scope.counter++: $scope.counter--;
                    $timeout(callback, 1000);
                };

                $timeout(callback, 1000);
            }
        };
    });

<body ng-controller="TimerController">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="timer in timers track by $index">
        </div>
        <timer counter="1000"></timer> <!-- these start at different times -->
        <timer counter="500"></timer> <!-- on page load they both have 1000-->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at this page on how to ask questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Your directive doesn't have its own scope, and it thus shares the same scope as the controller where it's used (`TimerController`). Make it use a child scope, with

```
scope: true
```

or an isolate scope, with

```
scope: {}
```

Comment: Clever answer +1 from me. :)

Comment: If he rendered those `timer` using `ng-repeat` then also it work as it uses `scope: true` internally